# How to include junit tests in maven-assembly-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a legacy app that builds the final jar using `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Problem: `mvn package` skips all `junit` tests (there have not been any so far).

Question: how can I force the assembly plugin to execute tests first before building the final jar?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>package_path.foo</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: maven-assembly-plugin does NOT execute any tests at all ... this is done by maven-surefire-plugin (unit tests) or maven-failsafe-plugin (integration tests) ... why do you package tests in the jar file? please show your full pom file and what you exactly like to achive ... also version information about plugins, maven, jdk etc. best would be an example project ...

Comment: You got me wrong: I don't package tests *into* the jar. I want the tests to execute (successfully) *before* the jar is packaged. It should be prevented if any test failed. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to execute the tests automatically during `mvn package`

Comment: Please show the full pom file... apart from that the usual life cycle run units tests (executed by maven-surefire-plugin and which is before the `package` phase ... I'm not sure If I understand your question or more accurate where your problem is? Maybe you could create a full example on github or alike .(and also posting the pom file here?)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the `maven-surefire-plugin` was missing. Comming from `spring-boot`, I was not aware this plugin has to be added explicit for executing `@Test` classes.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
  </plugin>
```